# Do philosophy of law questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the past, I've always asked questions that I would consider as "philosophy of law" in philosophy.SE, but now that our site is up, do they belong here? Or should we stick to relatively concrete questions on the law, as opposed to, say theories of punishment?
Examles: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23896/capital-punishment-and-morality
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/20034/german-philosophers-on-french-revolution

Comment: How would you define "philosophy of law"?

Comment: @HDE226868 From the Wikipedia article on the subject: "Philosophy of law is a branch of philosophy and jurisprudence that studies basic questions about law and legal systems, such as "what is law?", "what are the criteria for legal validity?", "what is the relationship between law and morality?", and many other similar questions"

Comment: At minimum you'd have to be careful to avoid a subjective question.

Comment: @Roy, Please link to those "philosophy of law" questions you have posted on philosophy.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say yes, and would further propose the following affirmative (i.e., non-exclusionary) scope test:  "If it is covered in law school, then it is in scope on Law.SE."

Comment: Many things unrelated to law are covered in law school too.  Are you sure we're going to apply "If it is covered in law school, then it is in scope on Law.SE"?

Comment: @Pacerier: I guess Abstract Logic is sometimes covered and would be better elsewhere.  What other Law School subjects would you consider potentially off-topic?

Comment: @feetwet Maybe writing?

Comment: @feetwet : Regarding this [comment](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/18598/106375#comment29968_19685), I would say this is legally not possible. This include U.S were stack exchange is based.

Comment: @feetwet, Morality, code of conduct plus ethics, office, writing, speech techniques to win a law case, etc.

Comment: I think that [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/63994/arent-laws-actually-just-logical-axioms) is an example where this answer applies, and should be reopened.

Comment: [If questions about philosophy of law are on-topic, then should it be explicitly stated in the help center?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1246/26060)

Answer (score 3):

Of the three examples you give in your comment, two are definitely on topic, and the other is potentially on topic.

- **What is law?** This is often the starting point of a legal education, often phrased as 'What are the sources of law?'  It's closely connected to the second example:
- **What are the criteria for legal validity?** This is an interesting legal question, and depending on the jurisdiction the answer may not be at all obvious.
- **What is the relationship between law and morality?**  I'm leaning towards this being on topic because issues of the morals of contemporary society are sometimes considered when a court examines old law, particularly in common-law systems.

Comment: There is a difference between what the community considers on-topic here, and what Stack Exchange is legally able to host.

Comment: what topics Stack Exchange are legally able to host?