# If questions about philosophy of law are on-topic, then should it be explicitly stated in the help center?

Tags: discussion, scope

From [Do philosophy of law questions belong here?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/58/26060), I guess the answer is yes.

If so, should this be explicitly stated in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Currently it only states these topics as on-topic:

> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals

Answer (score 2):

I would say that such questions are covered by:

> Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory

particularly the "theory" part.  But if there is a feeling that they are not so covered, then by all means edit that page to specify "philosophy of law".